Why doesn't showmount -a display mounted clients?
The NFSv4 showmount -a doesn't show the clients mounting an exported filesystem from a server. Is this functionality planned to be added in a future version or is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance

The manpage for mount mount says mount [-l] [-t type] is maintained for backward compatability and for more robust/customizable output use findmnt so something like: findmnt -l -t cifs

The rpc.mountd daemon doesn't keep track of this as NFSv4 doesn't use the MOUNT RPC protocol at all – clients do not request filehandles individually for each exported filesystem; there is only a single root (fsid=0) and an in-band NFS operation to obtain its handle, with all exports being implicitly accessible from that root handle.
This means that although (thanks to NFSv4 being explicitly stateful) you can find all active clients under /proc/fs/nfsd/clients – which are also logged by rpc.mountd to syslog on 5.3+ kernels – there is no way to reliably know which specific exports they have mounted as those handles are now obtained on-the-fly like any regular file handle.
Pure NFSv4 servers might not even speak the MOUNT protocol nor run the portmapper anymore, so the -a option of showmount (and anything else that talks to rpc.mountd over network) can be considered obsolete for NFSv4.
(Usually the NFSv4 server still runs rpc.mountd as the same daemon also handles local server-side calls from the kernel to verify each client against the exports ACL, but this doesn't exactly correspond to active mounts.)
